# Delayed copy rotation...?

Tags: constraints, drivers

I'm trying to make a constraint or some kind of system in 2.80, where i have a vehicle, driving on a path (follow path constraint, also rotating, but only on z axis) and a third person camera, attached to an empty following the vehicle. by using copy rotation, i can make the camera follow the vehicle without rotating and can then manually animate rotation. i just wonder if its possible to automate this, so that the camera will rotate on the z axis just like the vehicle on the path, only slightly delayed, but without delaying the location (preferably in real time). I know that the slow parent feature got removed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bake the motion to an empty and then edit the keyframes.

1. Add an empty.
2. Parent the empty to the vehicle and the camera to the empty.
3. Go to **Object > Animation > Bake** and simply check all the boxes, then press bake.
4. Now that the motion has been transfered onto the empty, open the graph editor and select the empty. You can edit the keyframes by selecting them and pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to smooth them or move them to a later frame with <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> confirm

[image: demo]

Comment: That seems to work. pity it can't run in real time, but workable